# MySQL Update gotcha? Is there something specific about UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a really simple procedure I need to do, and no matter how much I debug or simplify, the record is not updating in the dbase. Assume everything is correct in terms of connection, etc. Pulling this from php and doing a MySQL call in PHPMyAdmin results in a correct record update on the table. I've tried using/not using quotes around adminId.

Any ideas?

```
            $sampleString = "343r34c3cc43";


                //Need to store the customer ID from sub system

                $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("
                                UPDATE
                                    admins
                                   SET
                                   chargebeeId = '?'
                                   WHERE
                                   adminId='22'
                                   ");
                                $stmt2->bind_param('s',
                                    $mysqli->real_escape_string($sampleString)
                                );
                                $stmt2->execute();
```

For reference, adminId will be dynamic, with a bind_param 'i' in the application.

Comment: When you bind a parameter, you don't need to put quotes around it in the query.

Comment: Gordon I can't believe I missed this. Too many late nights! Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
  chargebeeId = '?'
```

to

```
 chargebeeId = ?
```

try this

```
 $sampleString = "343r34c3cc43";
 $sampleString = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sampleString) ;

            $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE admins
                                       SET chargebeeId = ?
                                       WHERE adminId='22' ");
            $stmt2->bind_param('s', $sampleString);
            $stmt2->execute();
```

Comment: Just needs a ; after the second line